# Missing Columns from DatabaseMetaData.getColumns()

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, database-metadata

The Java 7 Javadoc for **DatabaseMetaData.getColumns()** says it returns a **ResultSet** with 24 columns, the first named **TABLE_CAT** and the last named **IS_GENERATEDCOLUMN**. However, the result set I receive from Oracle has only 18 columns. I verified it with the following code:

```
DatabaseMetaData databaseMetaData = connection.getMetaData();
ResultSet set = databaseMetaData.getColumns(catalogName, schemaPattern,
        tableNamePattern, columnNamePattern);
final ResultSetMetaData resultSetData = set.getMetaData();
final int columnCount = resultSetData.getColumnCount();

for (int columnIndex = 1; columnIndex <= columnCount; ++columnIndex) {
   final String columnName = resultSetData.getColumnName(columnIndex);
   System.out.printf("Column %d: %s%n", columnIndex, columnName);
}
```

The above code produces this output:

```
Column 1: TABLE_CAT
Column 2: TABLE_SCHEM
Column 3: TABLE_NAME
Column 4: COLUMN_NAME
Column 5: DATA_TYPE
Column 6: TYPE_NAME
Column 7: COLUMN_SIZE
Column 8: BUFFER_LENGTH
Column 9: DECIMAL_DIGITS
Column 10: NUM_PREC_RADIX
Column 11: NULLABLE
Column 12: REMARKS
Column 13: COLUMN_DEF
Column 14: SQL_DATA_TYPE
Column 15: SQL_DATETIME_SUB
Column 16: CHAR_OCTET_LENGTH
Column 17: ORDINAL_POSITION
Column 18: IS_NULLABLE
```

Why don't I get all 24 columns? What am I missing?

Comment: *What am I missing?*: I'd say: a JDBC driver that respects the specifications.

Comment: Oracle are known for their faithful implementation of JDBC specs.

Comment: First of all you can simply print the columnCount to check the number of rows returned. Secondly you can check the `databaseMetaData.getColumns(catalogName, schemaPattern,
        tableNamePattern, columnNamePattern);`
if your **catalogName , columnNamePattern , tableNamePattern , schemaPattern** matches all the 24 columns or just the 18 - hope this helps

Comment: The procedure you describe is exactly what I did. However I get a column count of 18 instead of 24. Is it possible I need a different Oracle driver? I'm running Java 7, with this driver:  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
   <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
   <version>10.2.0.4.0</version>
   <type>jar</type>
   <scope>runtime</scope>
  </dependency>